# PySpark. How do I make sure the daily incremental data has NO duplicated UUID as PK in HIVE

Tags: pyspark, hive, uuid

I created a table in hive with UUID as Primary Key, for example

```
create table if not exists mydb.mytable as SELECT uuid() as uni_id, c.name, g.city, g.country 
FROM client c 
INNER JOIN geo g ON c.geo_id = g.id
```

Every day, I need to insert data to mytable, How do I make sure the daily incremental data has NO duplicated UUID as PK?

Answer (score 0):

If by UUID, what you're looking for is a series *Universally Unique Identifier*, then I think you can use an auto-increment id. In pure HQL, it can be achieved by `row_numer` and cross join.

```sql
insert overwrite table dest_tbl 
select
    a.rn + b.mid as id, col1, col2,...
from (
    select 
        *, row_number() over(order by rand()) as rn
    from src_tbl
) a 
join (select max(id) as mid from dst_tbl) b
```

Comment: I tried row_number,  as long as I found the max id of last ingestion, and add that id to the row_number, it works like a charm. However our goal is use UUID in daily incremental data. Any ideas? I appreciate your help!